# php-google-spreadsheet-client getByTitle returns empty result

Tags: php, google-sheets

I am using this library https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client to interact with Google's spreadsheet api.

Using the examples provided pretty much as is, I have this wip code:

```
    $accessToken = getToken();
    $serviceRequest = new DefaultServiceRequest($accessToken);  
    ServiceRequestFactory::setInstance($serviceRequest);
    $spreadsheetService = new Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetService();

    $spreadsheetFeed = $spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheets();
    print_r($spreadsheetFeed);
    echo $sheet=$spreadsheetFeed->getByTitle('sheetname');
```

The final line is unexpectedly printing null.